# Accessing Nested iframes from Extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I need to access a nested iframe at an arbitrary number of levels deep from a Firefox extension's overlay (an iframe within an iframe within an iframe within...). The overlay receives the event from the iframe, but the DOM accessor method returns nil.

```
function resizeIframe(evt){ 
var iframeHeight = evt.target.getAttribute("height");
var frame_id = evt.target.getAttribute("frame_id");
var ifr = content.document.getElementById('ifrm'+frame_id);//returns nil
ifr.style.height = iframeHeight+'px';
}
```

I'm looking for a robust way to do this, but I would be happy with anything that works at this point. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to access the same frame by ID if you already have `evt.target`?

Comment: I need to access the iframe's height attribute, which is in the iframe above the event.

Comment: Ok, I think you lost me here. So, what exact structure are you trying to work with and what is `event.target` in your case?

Comment: I am injecting an iframe onto a host pages via an extension. The injected iframe contains a script that fires a custom event, "IframeResizeEvent." That event is handled by the extension's overlay (code provided in the question). This works fine for a single iframe, but when my iframe is already inside an iframe, content.document.getElementById does not return anything because my iframe is within another iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`window.frameElement` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frameElement):

```js
var ifr = evt.target.ownerDocument.defaultView.frameElement;
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! Note: I believe this is specific to Firefox, but other browsers have similar methods.

Comment: @smcgregor: No, the `frameElement` property is supported by all browsers.

Comment: Good to hear. It will be a little while before I try this on other browsers, but I'll post another comment if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

From `Firefox 34` onward, we can point the developer tools at a specific iframe within a document.

You can refer to this [Mozilla Developer Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes) for detail explanation about extension provided by Mozilla to access nested iframes.